# Flutter UploadTask ambiguous import

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload image to Firebase storage as follows:

```
uploadToStorage() async{
    if (_productImage != null){
      print('ready to upload');
      FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
      Reference ref = storage.ref().child('apple');
      UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(_productImage);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

This is returning following error:

```
error: The name 'UploadTask' is defined in the libraries 'package:firebase/src/storage.dart (via 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' and 'package:firebase/firebase.dart')' and 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart'. (ambiguous_import at [aalxi_admin] lib\test_.dart:45)
```

What is the correct way to upload to Firebase storage?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Flutter Web if not you shouldn't use Firebase package it's for web and server usage. You can head over [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev) and follow the steps. Also as a temporary solution if Flutter Web is the case you can use `as` keyword for avoid this type issues.

```
package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart as firebaseStorage;
```

and use it with that prefix. like

```
firebaseStorage.UploadTask
```

Comment: Ok so you have to https://firebase.flutter.dev/ and just follow the steps.